# All Junit Test cases fail due to datetime format

Tags: java, junit

In my machine only all Junit test cases fails if date format is any thing except 2013-12-21. 
for example if date is **2007-03-30+01:00** then it will gives me this, expected:**<2007-03-[30 00]:00:00.0> but was:<2007-03-[29 23]:00:00.0>**

But in different machine it is running fine, can any body help me please, My os is Linux.

Input date: 2007-03-30+01:00

validate date: 2007-03-30 00:00:00.0

message: expected:<2007-03-[30 00]:00:00.0> but was:<2007-03-[29 23]:00:00.0>

Comment: The problem is the timezone. Your time seems to be in utc (usual on linux). For tests you schould creates timestamps with defined timezone (not so simple in java api), or date.getMillis() for comparsion of two date objects

Comment: My local machine timzone is BST

Comment: how do you creates dates in code?

Comment: <value><![CDATA[2007-03-30 00:00:00.0]]></value> in xml file for integration test

Comment: and you compairs xml string with the string representation of yor java Date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're comparing the `toString()`, which factors in locale.

Try comparing the raw date:

```
assertEquals(expectedDate, myDate);
```

or possibly the epoch time instead:

```
assertEquals(expectedDate.getTime(), myDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, But I can't do any changes in existing test cases, and also same test cases are running fine in different machine.

Comment: So try to set proper timezone, when running the tests (-Duser.timezone)

Comment: @subodh - Test cases that work on some machines and not others are broken.  Like it or not, this is a bug in the test.  Why aren't you allowed to fix bugs?  Isn't that kind of your job?

Comment: @DavidWallace, For the time being I can't fix this, I can rais a question only. But the thing is that these test cases are failed in only my machine. It's strange for me.

Comment: It's almost certainly because of your timezone settings, as others have pointed out.  But a test that relies on timezone settings to be a particular way is a buggy test, and should be fixed.

Comment: @DavidWallace, Thanks, Is it possible to fix on my local machine's timezone. But all the system's timezone is same that is BST.

Answer (score 0):

You have note shared your code but it seems the problem is that you may be using `java.util.Calendar` in your code, which is a timezone dependent api and may generate different results on different machinnes running in different timezone. If you have choice to change then you should consider using `java.util.Date`, as it is timezone-independent